# Perform a merge by date field without creating an auxiliary column in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Be the following DataFrames in python pandas:

```
|      date                   |     counter      |
|-----------------------------|------------------|
|  2022-01-01 10:00:02+00:00  |         34       |
|  2022-01-03 11:03:02+00:00  |         23       |
|  2022-02-01 12:00:05+00:00  |         12       |
|  2022-03-01 21:04:02+00:00  |         7        |
```

```
|      date                   |     holiday      |
|-----------------------------|------------------|
|  2022-01-01                 |       True       |
|  2022-01-02                 |       False      |
|  2022-01-03                 |       True       |
|  2022-02-01                 |       True       |
|  2022-02-02                 |       True       |
|  2022-02-03                 |       True       |
|  2022-03-01                 |       False      |
|  2022-03-02                 |       True       |
|  2022-03-03                 |       False      |
```

How could I merge both DataFrames taking into account that I don't want to create an auxiliary column with the date?

```
|      date                   |     counter      |   holiday    |
|-----------------------------|------------------|--------------|
|  2022-01-01 10:00:02+00:00  |         34       |    True      |
|  2022-01-03 11:03:02+00:00  |         23       |    True      |
|  2022-02-01 12:00:05+00:00  |         12       |    True      |
|  2022-03-01 21:04:02+00:00  |         7        |    False     |
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with datetimes without times by [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) - then helper column is not created in `df2` output:

```
df2['holiday'] = df2['date'].dt.normalize().map(df1.set_index('date')['holiday'])
```

Another idea with [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), but for avoid error need remove timezones by [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(date = df1['date'].dt.tz_convert(None)).sort_values('date'), 
                   df2, on='date')
print (df)
                 date  counter  holiday
0 2022-01-01 10:00:02       34     True
1 2022-01-03 11:03:02       23     True
2 2022-02-01 12:00:05       12     True
3 2022-03-01 21:04:02        7    False
```

Comment: What if the second DataFrame has more than 2 columns? Not only the date and holiday columns.

Comment: The another idea has an error: 
MergeError: incompatible merge keys [0] datetime64[ns, UTC] and dtype('<M8[ns]'), must be the same type

Comment: @Carola - Can you check now?

Comment: Now it appears this error: ValueError: left keys must be sorted

Comment: @Carola - You can add `.sort_values('date')`, answer was edited.